# Why does my pygame only display the first frame and not render the updates?

Tags: python, pygame, game-development

I'm trying to get a a set number of blocks move around on the screen and have collision
however it only draws the very first position of the blocks and doesn't draw any of the later frames, that is the acutal movement of the blocks

here is my code

https://github.com/Zippzy/pygame-testing

please help

Comment: Please don't post links to repos. Post a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

This part here is wrong. `move` returns a new, moved rect. You want to move the rectangles in place, which is `move_ip`.
So change

```
for i in objects:
    i.Rect.move(i.speed)
```

to

```
for i in objects:
    i.Rect.move_ip(i.speed)
```